# Problem .gitlab-ci.yml [ Mysql connection error]

Tags: laravel, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I allow myself to post a topic in support as I am stuck for a few days on a problem with gitlab’s CI configuration file for a Laravel project

My .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy
    - prod

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - node_modules/
    - .yarn

build env file:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - sed -i  “s/{{DB_USER}}/$MYSQL_USER/g” .env
    - sed -i “s/{{DB_PASSWORD}}/$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD/g” .env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env.example

composer:
    stage: build
    image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
    cache:
        key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
        paths:
            - vendor/
    script:
        - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 1 month
        paths:
            - vendor/
            - .env

yarn:
    stage: build
    image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
    cache:
        key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-npm
        paths:
            - node_modules/
            # - Modules/mon-mondules/node_modules/ si utilisation de modules supplementaire
    script:
        - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
        - yarn install --pure-lockfile
            # - cd Modules/mon-modules/node_modules/ && npm install $$ npm run production
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 1 month
        paths:
            - public/css/
            - public/js/
            - public/modules/
            - public/mix-manifest.json

testing:
    stage: test
    services:
        - mysql:5.7
    image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
    script:
        # - ./vendor/bin/security-checker security:check
        - ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit --no-coverage
      

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
  dependencies:
    - build env file
  script:
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
    

deploying to prod:
  stage: prod
  image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
  script:
    - echo "Deploy all the things!"
    
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

The first two stages worked well but arrived at the Testing stage, the pipeline failed with the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

I don’t know how to solve this problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you set variables in `.Gitlab-CI.yml`, the runner knows about them, but Laravel won’t. You have to put these variables in your `.env` file. The way I do it is to put values like “`{{DB_PASSWORD}}`” in `.env.example`:

```sh
# .env.example
# ...
DB_USER=“{{DB_USER}}”
DB_PASSWORD=“{{DB_PASSWORD}}
# ...
```

Then I replace those placeholders with the actual values. For situations where I’m using actual databases (like in production pipelines) I use CI Variables which you can define in the Project’s or the Group’s CI settings.

```yaml
testing:

    stage: test

    services:

        - mysql:5.7

    image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine

    script:

        - cp .env.example .env

        - sed -i “s/{{DB_USER}}/$MYSQL_USER/g” .env
        - sed -i “s/{{DB_PASSWORD}}/$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD/g” .env

        - php artisan key:generate

        - php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

        - ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit --no-coverage

        #- php artisan code:analyse
```

The `sed` command can do a number of things but here we only care about string substitution. The syntax `sed -i “s/{{DB_USER}}/g” .env` means:

- `-i` tells sed to edit the file inline
- the `s` before the delimiter says we’re doing substitution.
- the item after the first delimiter is the value that will be replaced. Using placeholders in this way is easy since they’re unique and simple to identify
- The item after the next delimiter is what we’re replacing it with
- The `g` at the end means “global”: replace all instances in the file.
- `.env` is the file we’re working with

When using an image that doesn't have `sed` (or you just want to separate your config generation from your deploy step), you can upload the `.env` file as an artifact:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

build env file:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - sed -i  “s/{{DB_USER}}/$MYSQL_USER/g” .env
    - sed -i “s/{{DB_PASSWORD}}/$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD/g” .env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env.example

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-alpine
  dependencies:
    - build env file
  script:
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
    # ...
```

There's a lot to unpack here. First, the image used here doesn't really matter as long as it has `sed` available. Alpine linux is a super small (and fast) linux distribution I frequently use for tasks like this. After we modify our `.env` file, we're uploading it to Gitlab as a job artifact.

By default, all jobs in subsequent stages will download all artifacts of previous stages. We can control this with the `dependencies` keyword. When a job has this keyword, only artifacts from those jobs will be downloaded. If no artifacts are needed, you can use `dependencies: []`. So the `deploy` job will get the `.env` file from the `build env file` job and has it available for the `artisan` commands.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but this "sed" command  is "unsupported command �" during this stage testing
Can it come from the docker image?

Comment: Ah, it must not be in your image. I'll edit my answer with an alternative.

Comment: I don't understand, this sed command is still "unsupported command"

Comment: Can you update your post with what your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file contains now?

Comment: I know this is old, but this may help someone down the road. You can include `sed` into alpine by placing `apk add sed` before the `sed` commands.